# How to populate without a ref in mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Question, I'm trying to populate a model without the ref. The reason is the objectId that I want to save is coming from two different models. My plan is in my controller I will populate two model and I'm just gonna include a if statement on which value should be pass on in the front end part.

**Model**

```
const sampleSchema= mongoose.Schema({
creatorId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'accountModel',
  },
  whoCanEdit: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide who can edit the project'],
  },
  whoCanEditId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

**Controller**

```
export const getProjectById = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const project = await sampleModel
      .findById(req.params.id)
      .populate('creatorId');

    if (project.whoCanEdit === 'Specific') {
      <---this where I'm planning to populate
    }

    res.status(200).json(project);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ msg: error.message });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Dynamic References](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref)

add another field to your schema and store the model name for populate

```
whoCanEditId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    refPath: 'editType'
},
editType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
}
```

if `whoCanEdit` is the name of model you can use it instead of adding `editType`

and simply use it like before

```
.populate('whoCanEditId')
```